# Locate the script writing a particular log

Tags: files, logs

I have a path where some log files are been written to. I also know these file names. How can I know the location of the script writing these log files?

Comment: The filenames of the logs, and a few lines of the file (redacted as necessary) would be helpful. It would at least help decide whether these were system or user logs.The file `ls -l` showing user, dates and times would also help, e.g. being matched to cron entries or user logins.

Comment: `lsof` command should write all open files and which processes are opening/accessing/writing them. `lsof | grep <log filename>` should filter the process writing to that log. If that does not work for you, search for log filename in /etc/ directory. Maybe it is specified in some config file. Many times log entries include process ID. Search for that process with `ps`command.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsof /path/to/logfiles/filename.log
```

will show you the name of the process using `filename.log` (that is, keeping `filename.log` open for writing).